# When using the Camera object, can I set it to make smaller pictures if needed?

Tags: android

In my app I have a SurfaceHolder and I use a camera to capture a photo:

```
private void initCamera() {
    try {
        camera = Camera.open();
        if (camera == null) {
            camera = openFrontFacingCamera();
        }
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My question is:

**Can I set the camera to take smaller photos, in case I need it, instead of it taking the highest resolution possible photos?**

Comment: You can use setPictureSize() on the camera parameters object to configure the size of the picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Firstly determine supported resolutions and after that set to parameters the one you need:

```
Camera.Parameters p = camera.getParameters();
p.setRotation(90);
p.setJpegQuality(100);
List<Size> sizes = p.getSupportedPictureSizes();
for (int i=0;i<sizes.size();i++) {
    Log.e("", "Size: " + sizes.get(i).width + " " + sizes.get(i).height);
}
//determine appropriate and set:
p.setPictureSize(sizes.get(0).width, sizes.get(0).height);
```